# Unable to Trigger UserDetailsService' loadUserByUsername Method in Spring Security OAuth2 Password Mode

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, authorization, spring-security-oauth2

I encountered an issue while configuring an OAuth2 authorization server using Spring Security. I've set up AuthorizationServerConfig with a custom UserDetailsService (userServiceDetailsServiceImpl). However, when performing OAuth2 authentication in password mode, I'm unable to trigger the loadUserByUsername method.

I attempted to access the /oauth/token endpoint using Basic Authentication, ensuring that the provided username and password are correct. Despite configuring UserDetailsService, I couldn't reach the loadUserByUsername method within the UserServiceDetailsServiceImpl.

[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoaef.png)

**Related Code Snippet:**

```
@EnableAuthorizationServer // 开启授权服务器
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Qualifier("userServiceDetailsServiceImpl")
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    /**
     * 配置验证管理器，UserdetailService
     */
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .tokenStore(jwtTokenStore()) // jwt 来存储我们的token
                .tokenEnhancer(jwtAccessTokenConverter());  // jwt还需要设置决定token的产生方式
        super.configure(endpoints);
    }

    private TokenStore jwtTokenStore() {
        JwtTokenStore jwtTokenStore = new JwtTokenStore(jwtAccessTokenConverter());
        return jwtTokenStore;
    }

    public JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter(){
        JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtAccessTokenConverter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        // 加载我们的私钥
        ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("coinexchange.jks");
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory =
                new KeyStoreKeyFactory(classPathResource, "coinexchange".toCharArray());
        jwtAccessTokenConverter.setKeyPair(
                keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("coinexchange", "coinexchange".toCharArray()));
        return jwtAccessTokenConverter;
    }
}
```

```
@EnableResourceServer
@Configuration
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {}
```

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    /**
     * 密码加密
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class UserServiceDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        ServletRequestAttributes requestAttributes = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        String loginType = requestAttributes.getRequest().getParameter("login_type");   // 区分后台人员还是用户
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(loginType)) {
            throw new AuthenticationServiceException("登陆类型不能为null");
        }
        UserDetails userDetails = null;
        try {
            switch (loginType) {
                case LoginConstant.ADMIN_TYPE:
                    userDetails =  loadSysUserByUsername(s); // 后台人员的登录
                    break;
                case LoginConstant.MEMBER_TYPE:
                    userDetails = loadMemberUserByUsername(s);  // 普通会员登录
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new AuthenticationServiceException("暂不支持的登陆方式：" + loginType);
            }
        }catch (IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException e) { // 用户不存在
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("用户名" + s + "不存在");
        }
        return userDetails;
    }
    /**
     * 后台管理员登录
     * @param username
     * @return
     */
    private UserDetails loadSysUserByUsername(String username) {
        // 1. 使用用户名查询用户
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(LoginConstant.QUERY_ADMIN_SQL, new RowMapper<User>() {
            @Override
            public User mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                if(resultSet.wasNull()) {
                    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("用户名" + username + "不存在");
                }
                long id = resultSet.getLong("id");  // 用户id
                String password = resultSet.getString("password");  // 用户密码
                int status = resultSet.getInt("status");    // 用户状态
                return new User(   // 3. 封装成一个USerDetails对象，返回
                        String.valueOf(id), // 使用id->username
                        password,
                        status == 1,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        getSysUserPermissions(id)           // 2. 查询该用户的权限
                );
            }
        }, username);
    }

    /**
     * 通过用户id查询用户的权限
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getSysUserPermissions(long id) {
        // 1. 当用户为超级管理员，他拥有所有的权限
        String roleCode = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(LoginConstant.QUERY_ROLE_CODE_SQL, String.class);
        List<String> permissions = null;    // 权限的名称
        if(LoginConstant.ADMIN_ROLE_CODE.equals(roleCode)) {    // 超级管理员
            permissions = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(LoginConstant.QUERY_ALL_PERMISSIONS, String.class);
        }
        else {          // 2. 普通用户，需要使用角色->权限
            permissions = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(LoginConstant.QUERY_PERMISSION_SQL, String.class, id);
        }
        if(permissions == null || permissions.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
        return permissions.stream()
                .distinct()     // 去重
                .map(perm->new SimpleGrantedAuthority(perm))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

```
server:
  port: 9999
spring:
  application:
    name: authorization-server
  cloud:
    nacos:
      discovery:
        server-addr: nacos-server:8848
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/coin-exchange?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&characterEncoding=utf-8
    username: root
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**Expected Outcome:**
I expect to enter the loadUserByUsername method within the UserServiceDetailsServiceImpl during OAuth2 password mode authentication to validate the user's identity.

**Attempted Solutions**:

Properly injected UserDetailsService in AuthorizationServerConfig and configured it in AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer.
Checked Basic Authentication configurations and headers to ensure correct username and password input.
Verified logging; there are no records indicating the invocation of the loadUserByUsername method.

**Requesting Help:**

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? How was it resolved?
What aspects should I check to determine why the loadUserByUsername method isn't triggered?
Are there other factors that might affect OAuth2 password mode authentication?
Thank you very much for your assistance and suggestions!

Comment: BTW: `spring-security.oauth2` is end of life since 2022. You should update to Spring Security 5/6. Furthermore, ressource owner grant type should not be used. It is a security risk. Therefore, Spring Security 5/6 doesnt't support it anymore.

Comment: You didn't post your client registration. However, AFAIR the token endpoint is secured with basic authentication. You have to provide client ID and client credential to access the token endpoint.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and guidance! I'm in the process of learning Spring Security, and I did make a rookie mistake by not configuring the client details properly. Your reminder has been incredibly helpful and made me aware of this oversight.